# Android - Uploading to Dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Am I missing something here? My code is kicking a NullPointerException based on this code to upload to Dropbox.

```
File file = new File(mFileMag.getCurrentDir() +"/"+ mSelectedListItem);
System.out.println(file);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
System.out.println(inputStream);
Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/" + mSelectedListItem, inputStream,
        file.length(), null, null); 
System.out.println(newEntry);
```

The results of the system.out commands look ok. The inputStream variable outputs "java.io.FileInputStream@44ecd668" which I'm a little confused about but the systemout for the file variable displays the right path and filename. The nullPointerException seems to be coming from the setting of the newEntry variable which makes zero sense to me. Eclipse shows the code as being syntactically correct. This dropbox crap is killing me.

@BenHolland -- If I hardcode the paths as below --

```
 case D_MENU_SEND:

            // Uploading content.
            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                //File file = new File(mFileMag.getCurrentDir() +"/"+ mSelectedListItem);
                File file = new File("/sdcard0/DCIM/100ANDRO/deploy.json");
                System.out.println(file);
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                System.out.println(inputStream);
                Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/Dropbox/", inputStream,
                        file.length(), null, null); 
                System.out.println(newEntry);

                Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + newEntry.rev);
            } catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) {
                // User has unlinked, ask them to link again here.
                Log.e("DbExampleLog", "User has unlinked.");
            } catch (DropboxException e) {
                Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("DbExampleLog", "File not found.");
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        inputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {}
                }
            }
```

This simply generates a "File not found" in logcat which of course is coming from catch (FileNotFoundException). I don't however receive the NullPointerException. If you see at the top of the code -- the case statement -- this code is being run after a context menu click.

_____________________________________Updated code__________________________________________

```
 // Uploading content.
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;

        File upfile = new File(mFileMag.getCurrentDir() + "/" + mSelectedListItem);
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(upfile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(upfile);
        System.out.println(inputStream);

        try {
            Entry upEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/test.rar", inputStream,upfile.length(), null, null);
            System.out.println(upEntry);
        } catch (DropboxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So I've updated the code to this. Whether I hardcode the paths or not seems to be irrelevant. Even If I do, the Entry upEntry line is causing a NullPointerException. I'm at a loss. I cant see anything at all that would be causing this.

________________________________Stack trace from nullPointerException_______________________

```
02-14 13:28:07.370: W/dalvikvm(311): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.stavox.zircon.Main.onContextItemSelected(Main.java:722)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2199)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2744)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:137)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:874)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-14 13:28:07.380: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is the stack trace which occurs when I click "Send to Dropbox" . I think if I break down the whole process it might make it easier for someone to help.

1. App launches to a list view - its a file manager app - main.java
2. The user clicks a button on the menu that launches the dropbox authorization - the button loads DropboxfileuploadActivity.java - Thats where the auth is done - this returns them to main.java after auth.
3. User navigates to file they want to upload
4. The user long clicks on said file and a context menu appears - this is handled by Main.java as well.
5. The context menu contains a "Send To Dropbox" item. When clicked, it points to the case statement containing the code we have been looking at here. Thats what is generating the NullPointerException. As you can see above line 722 is the offending line. That line is the

   ```
    Entry upEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/test.rar", inputStream,upfile.length(), null, null);
   ```

   _____________________________________________Solution_______________________________________

So here's what I ended up doing to solve this:

Previously I was working between two files. I had the Dropbox authcode in Main.java, and the actual upload code in Dropboxfileuploadactivity.java. No matter what I tried, I could not get the upload to work this way. I received a NullPointerException every time. I initially blamed it on the variables and not being able to use then with the Dropbox methods. After days of trying to figure it out, in the end, moving the auth code and the upload code together in to Main.java is what solved my issue. No more NullPointerExceptions. Odd, but it worked. The variables work fine.

Comment: Can you print a stack trace or something?  You haven't given enough information for anyone to really help you, aside from wild guesses.

Comment: Can you do this with a hardcoded file successfully?  Here is an example -> https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/index.html

Comment: @BenHolland -- I added further info and code to the bottom of the original post.

Comment: The docs ( https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#putFile(java.lang.String, java.io.InputStream, long, java.lang.String, com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener) ) say that the path should point to a file, i.e., including file name. It looks like you're just supplying "/Dropbox/" which may be the issue. (Also, unless you actually mean to upload to a folder named "Dropbox" nested inside the Dropbox account itself, you don't need to include that.)

Comment: I added some updated code above....Its still throwing a NullPoinerException with hard coded paths...I also did what @Greg recommended.When I tried it with hard paths I verified that they were correct..If anyone has any ideas or knows of anyone to figure out the NullPointer, i'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: Sounds like your file isn't really there.  What does is the value of "String myFilePath = new File(mFileMag.getCurrentDir() +"/"+ mSelectedListItem).getAbsolutePath();"?  Does it match what you hardcoded the file as?  Which line is the exception coming from?  Check the stack trace to get line number. If its not coming from the upFile variable, Greg is probably correct.  Also should "/test.rar" be "./test.rar"?  The . is a relative file path, you gave it an absolute file path to the root directory.

Comment: @BenHolland -- About the value you asked about. Yours returns the same value as my mFileMag.getCurrentDir() + "/" + mSelectedListItem . But as far as what Greg recommended, it doesnt matter what I try for the dropbox path, this still occurs. The issue is occurring on the putfile line.

Comment: @BenHolland -- I think I may have found something. Can someone tell me why this:

`File upfile = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "/" + mSelectedListItem);`

would report a completely different path to the file than this:

`File upfile = new File(mFileMag.getCurrentDir() + "/" + mSelectedListItem);`

The first path reports the file path as being located in the protected data dir. This gets weirder every day!

Comment: Geeze I FINALLY FIXED IT!!! I still dont get why it would not work previously but I added my solution to the initial code entries up top. Read there for the solution. Thanks to everyone that helped me!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So heres what I ended up doing to solve this:

Previously I was working between two files. I had the Dropbox authcode in Main.java, and the actual upload code in Dropboxfileuploadactivity.java. No matter what I tried, I could not get the upload to work this way. I received a NullPointerException every time. I initially blamed it on the variables and not being able to use then with the Dropbox methods. After days of trying to figure it out, in the end, moving the auth code and the upload code together in to Main.java is what solved my issue. No more NullPointerExceptions. Odd, but it worked. The variables work fine.